# Visual Studio 2017 unable to connect to Nuget

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-server

i have a problem, 
when i tried to Manage Nuget Packages VS2017 showed me this message:

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. 
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a    send.
  Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Please can you help me to solve this problem?? 
I'm going crazy
Thank you

Comment: I think you'd better contact MS support about that. Other than that, I'd try to check if you can access the mentioned URL from browser, and if you can't, try to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

That is a bug in VS 2017. (I had the same problem). This has been fixed in VS version 15.1 . To fix this problem update your VS through vs_Community.exe installer (which you can download [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/whatsnew/)).